# Python error_time data does not match format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working with a CSV file which contain daily weather data for different month, i am trying to monthly aggregating the daily data using below script,

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime,format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M') 
data.index = data.Timestamp
df = df.resample('W').mean()
```

I am getting the following error,

[Input file description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOyOc.jpg)

```
time data '01-01-2000 00:00' does not match format '%d-%m-%y %H:%M' (match)
```

How to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%Y` for match `YYYY`, if use `%y` it match `YY` format of year:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime,format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```

Then create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('W').mean()
```

Comment: Hi, i rectified the code suggested by you, still its producing error,

`df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime,format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') `
 `data.index = df.Timestamp`
  `df = df.resample('W').mean()`  

Error massage 
`Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`

Comment: Yes, now it is working correctly. Thanks. Can you plz explain where was the error.

Comment: Format of years is `YYYY` like `2015`, so need `%Y`

Answer (score 0):

Or create a separate Month column from your date column and then do aggregate

```
df.date  = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).month
```

Comment: Hi, this script is running fine, but how do i aggregate, when i use the below comment, i am getting error
Script:
`df = df.resample('W').mean()`

error massage
`Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'`